# React router 4 and path params in layouts

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I'm having trouble understanding how to access path params through React Router 4 in a layout component.

The system has pages for managing projects which are accessible at routes containing the project id, such as `/projects/1`, `/projects/2` etc.
There are also other non-project pages which use the same layout, such as `/settings`.

The layout renders a nav bar at the top of the page which should contain a project menu if a project is selected. I.e. the project menu should be shown at `/projects/:projectId`, but not at `/settings`.

Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve:
https://codesandbox.io/s/18vm42n417

Any help appreciated!

This is the code from the codesandbox.io link:

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const ProjectMenu = () => (
  <div>
    Project menu<br />
    <small>(should only be visible on project pages)</small>
  </div>
)

const NavBar = () => (
  <div style={{
    backgroundColor: 'deepPink',
    padding: 32
  }}>
    {/*
      How can I check for the projectId path param here
      and render the project menu only if it is set?
      Note that the /settings page should not have
      the project menu.
    */}
    <ProjectMenu />
  </div>
)

const Layout = ({ children }) => (
  <div style={{
    backgroundColor: 'hotPink',
  }}>
    <NavBar />
    <div style={{
      padding: 64
    }}>
      {children}
    </div>
  </div>
)

const Start = () => (
  <div>
    <Link to='/projects/1'>Project 1</Link><br />
    <Link to='/projects/2'>Project 2</Link><br />
    <Link to='/settings'>Settings</Link>
  </div>
)

const Project = ({match}) => (
  <div>
    Project {match.params.projectId}<br /><br />
    <Link to='/'>Back</Link>
  </div>
)

const Settings = () => (
  <div>
    Settings<br /><br />
    <Link to='/'>Back</Link>
  </div>
)

const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Layout style={{ padding: 64 }}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/projects/:projectId' component={Project} />
        <Route path='/settings' component={Settings} />
        <Route path='/' component={Start} />
      </Switch>
    </Layout>
  </BrowserRouter>
)

render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Comment: So what is the issue? To hide `NavBar` on settings page?

Comment: @seethrough To hide the `ProjectMenu` on the settings page.

Comment: try moving it from `Layout` straight to `Project` then? or did you try that?

Comment: Well, the problem is that the `ProjectMenu` should be inside the `NavBar`, so I can't really move it into the `Project` component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this you want to do?

```
 const NavBar = () => (
      <div style={{
        backgroundColor: 'deepPink',
        padding: 32
      }}>
        {/*
          How can I check for the projectId path param here
          and render the project menu only if it is set?
          Note that the /settings page should not have
          the project menu.
        */}
        <Route path='/projects/:projectId' component={ProjectMenu} />
      </div>
    )
```

And you can receive projectID in this way.

```
const ProjectMenu = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    Project menu<br />
    <small>(should only be visible on project pages)</small>
    {match.params.projectId}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Yes, I want to show the `ProjectMenu` only for project pages, e.g. `/projects/1`, `projects/2` etc.

Comment: You can use Route to define where component should display according to the path.

Comment: The difference between v3 and v4 is that we don't need to write all the Routes in the same place.